# How to Query tables to get records having no record in link and records with filter as well

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables as belows:

```
translation_token
-----------------
id   token    default_value
--   ------   -------------
1    token_1  Token 1
2    token_2  Token 2
3    token_3  Token 3

translation_token_value
-----------------------
id   token_id   language_id   value
--   --------   -----------   -----
1    1               1        Token 1 english
2    1               2        Token 1 dutch
3    2               1        Token 2 english

application_module
------------------
id   name
--   ----
1    project
2    location


LI_translation_token_application_module
---------------------------------------
id   token_id   application_module_id
--   --------   ---------------------
1       1               1        
2       2               2
```

I have translation_token table if there is a translation available for specific language then its entry will be present in translation_token_value table otherwise default_translation to be fetched for token and not null.

Also these tokens are for either for specific modules or open for all modules. If these tokens are for modules then there will be link in LI_translation_token_application_module table otherwise there will not be any entry.

While fetching records I always have modules and language_id for filter, so that I will get translations for specific modules and language and along with that general translations i.e. tokens applicable for all modules.

So far I tried below query but didn't get success. I am not getting tokens which don't have translation in translation_token_value so that for such token default_translation will be visible.

```
SELECT translation_token.token, ttv.value,
CASE WHEN ttv.value = NULL THEN translation_token.default_translation
      ELSE ttv.value
END
FROM translation_token 
LEFT OUTER JOIN translation_token_value AS ttv ON ttv.token_id = translation_token.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN LI_translation_token_application_module AS token_app_mod ON token_app_mod.token_id = ttv.token_id
LEFT JOIN application_module 
ON application_module.id = token_app_mod.application_module_id
WHERE (application_module.name IN('project') OR application_module.name IS NULL)  
AND (language_id = 2 OR language_id is null)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem in the left join with “LI_translation_token_application_mod”  use the default token table "translation_token" not the token value table "translation_token_value". Like below

```
SELECT translation_token.token, ttv.value,
CASE WHEN ttv.value  Is NULL THEN translation_token.default_translation
  ELSE ttv.value
END
FROM translation_token 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  translation_token_value AS ttv ON ttv.token_id = translation_token.id and ttv.language_id=2
LEFT OUTER JOIN LI_translation_token_application_module AS token_app_mod ON token_app_mod.token_id = translation_token.token_id
LEFT JOIN application_module 
ON application_module.id = token_app_mod.application_module_id
WHERE (application_module.name  IN('project') OR application_module.name IS NULL)
```

Comment: You also need to change `WHEN ttv.value = NULL` to `WHEN ttv.value IS NULL`

Comment: @EidMorsy Thanks for finding my mistake. But this just solve problem to fetch tokens which are not present in LI table. This query still will not work if there is no record for token in translation_token_value table for any language.

Comment: I've Edited the query to use the "language_id=2" in the join itself. it should working as expecting